# URL link to Twitter user with ID, not name

Tags: twitter, permalinks

I want to have a link to my twitter page that references it with my twitter ID and not twitter name. This is because I want to build the link into an app and the twitter name for the account may change in future.

Comment: Any chance on telling us what programming language you want this in?

Comment: I was just looking for a URL weblink.

Comment: So instead of www.twitter.com/someaccount I would like to refer to that page with someaccount's id.

Comment: This is unfortunate twitter does this.  I was hoping you could do something like twitter.com/?id=819999.  Facebook and LinkedIn both have ability to use the id instead of the username.

Answer (score 100):

After struggling with this issue for a while, found a solution which works on mobile:

```
https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=XXX
```

Source: https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/3386

Comment: Works as of April 12, 2018. Thanks.

Comment: Works on desktop too!

Comment: if you only have the username you could do `https://twitter.com/intent/user?screen_name=XXXX`

Comment: Works as of Jan 4, 2022. I should mention it displays a popup suggesting to follow the account though. If that's something you'd rather avoid, use the `https://twitter.com/i/user/2857023470` approach suggested by Mert S. Kaplan below

Answer (score 84):

**UPDATE**: This answer doesnt work after 2013 (Read the [official response](https://twittercommunity.com/t/how-to-redirect-to-a-user-profile-with-its-user-id/22646/2) in twitter's forum). For an alternate method see [quarkon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20211109/243557).

Original Answer:

---

Use ID in the end of this url, like:

https://twitter.com/account/redirect_by_id/783214

Comment: You can also make it look a little more pretty: https://twitter.com/account/redirect_by_id/76816072 - unfortunately still does not work when Twitter does a mobile redirect to the mobile.twitter.com subdomain.

Comment: This method no longer works on desktop either and will return a 404 error page.

Answer (score 48):

You can use new URL structure: https://twitter.com/i/user/50988711

**Note:** At the point of referral to mobile application is not yet stable.

Comment: Is this URL documented somewhere?

Comment: make this answer accepted. A lot has changed since 2013

Comment: Looks like this is documented here https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/web-intents/overview